# php pagination in function

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Im trying to put a pagination in a table.
I have this function inside a class called Login that echo a part of a table:

```
public function getCodes()
{
    // if database connection opened
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $query_codes = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT i.id, i.code, i.active, p.enterprise, (SELECT count(*) FROM internal) AS total FROM internal AS i LEFT JOIN pusers AS p ON i.user_id = p.user_id');
        $query_codes->execute();
        // get result row (as an object)
        //$result_row = $query_products->fetchObject();
        while ($result_row = $query_codes->fetchObject()){
            $this->totalPages = $result_row->total;
            echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
            echo '<td>'.$result_row->code.'</td><td>'.$result_row->active.'</td><td>'.$result_row->enterprise.'</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="codes">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$result_row->id.'>
                    <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="button" name="delete_code" onclick="return confirm(\'Quieres borrar el Código?\')">Borrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="button" name="activate_code" onclick="return confirm(\'Quieres activar el Código?\')">Activar</button>
                </form>
            </td>'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
            echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in another file i call it like this:

```
<div class="table-style">
            <table class="table-list">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Activo</th>
                    <th>Empresa</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                <?php $login->getCodes();?>
            </tbody></table>
 </div>
```

The question is how can i transform this to have a pagination in the table?

Answer (score 0):

The following example will be based on URL parameters:

1. We'll need to set how many rows should be generated.
2. In the URL we will use "page" parameter to determine which table page would generate.

   ```
   function getCodes(){

       $maxRows = 10;
       $offset = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

       if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
           $query_codes = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT i.id, i.code, i.active, p.enterprise, (SELECT count(*) FROM internal) AS total FROM internal AS i LEFT JOIN pusers AS p ON i.user_id = p.user_id' . ' LIMIT '.$maxRows.' OFFSET '. ($offset * $maxRows));
           $query_codes->execute();
           // get result row (as an object)
           //$result_row = $query_products->fetchObject();
           while ($result_row = $query_codes->fetchObject()){
               $this->totalPages = $result_row->total;
               echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
               echo '<td>'.$result_row->code.'</td><td>'.$result_row->active.'</td><td>'.$result_row->enterprise.'</td>
               <td>
                   <form method="post" action="codes">
                       <input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$result_row->id.'>
                       <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="button" name="delete_code" onclick="return confirm(\'Quieres borrar el Código?\')">Borrar</button>
                       <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="button" name="activate_code" onclick="return confirm(\'Quieres activar el Código?\')">Activar</button>
                   </form>
               </td>'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
               echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
           }
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

Now in your url just add the `page` param as follows:

http://localhost/you-page-with-table/**?page=1**